# Check whether the NSArray object at index is of kind NSString Or NSNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

This is my NSArray : 
(
    "tag_name",
    3,
    "mp4_url",
    4,
    0,
    "back_tag",
    5,
    1,
    "part_id",
    "related_list",
    2
)

I need to put all the numerical values in some another array.
I used the following code to check whether the value fetched from the array was a numeric or a string,  but it didn't work. Every time i get the value from an array as NSString.

```
for (int i=0; i<arr.count; i++) {

    id obj=[arr objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    {
        // It's an NSString, do something with it...
        NSLog(@"its string");
    }else{

        // It's an Numerical value, do something with it...
        NSLog(@"its integer value");

    }

}
```

I know that array stores only kind of objects in it, so while fetching i'm getting the value as NSString(i.e object). But is there anyway to check whether the value stored was a numeric value.
Please can anyone help me..
Thanks

Comment: "It doesn't work" is possibly the least helpful description of what is or isn't happening. What did you expect? What did you see happening? Explain "It doesn't work".

Comment: Where is the sorting logic ? whats not working ?

Comment: Try this rather then isKindOfclass, if ([obj respondsToSelector:@selector(numberWithFloat:)]){// is a nsnumber}. If you want to check for NSString just find something it only does, i.e: stringWithFormat

Comment: I think your numbers are in string format since array takes only object type. from where you are getting the records/

Comment: @Fogmeister : What i actually want is to fetch all the numeric values from the NSArray and put them some another array. I'm not able to identify whether the current value fetched from the array is a numeric value or NSString.

Comment: @Mahesh yes, but what isn't working? You said it doesn't work but you didn't say how or why it is not working? (Note: "I'm not able" is about as useful as "It doesn't work"). WHY are you not able? etc...

Comment: @VinodJat: Yes as the array stores objects, while fetching the values i get all the values from the array as a string. But is there some way to check whether its numeric value?

Comment: @Mahesh boom! There you go! Wasn't difficult. Why didn't you say "all the values from the array ore strings"? That would instantly make answering the question a lot easier.

Comment: If that code says it's an NSString it's because it's an NSString.  When you NSLog an NSArray it only puts quotes around elements that contain "special" characters such as blank or underline.

Comment: @HotLicks in what way? If my answer is wrong, why so?  http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/9jWyuFZ0Ygvbe2YzzWcc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just turn an `NSString` into an `NSNumber` but there are ways that you can try to get he numeric value out of them.

This is one option but you could also have a look at `NSNumberFormatter`.

If all of the numbers are integers then you could do something like this...

```
// always use fast enumeration
for (NSString *string in arr) {

    NSInteger integer = [string integerValue];

    // have to check explicitly for 0 as a non-numeric would return 0 above
    if ([string isEqualToString:@"0"]
        || integer != 0) {
        // it is an integer numeric string
    } else {
        // it is a string
    }

}
```